# Using `find( )` and selecting the parent element as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to create a highlight effect for a while now. This is extremely close to what I need however, the problem with this method is it leaves out the inner most parent element.

What I need is the exact same functionality as what the below JQuery code produces, the only difference is, I would like to include the inner-most parent object as well. Using `find` finds all children of the parent object, which is not exactly what I need.

### **Edit**

I basically need the combination of these two statements:

```
$last.parent().parent().find('*').effect("highlight", {color: '#FCF8DC'}, 2000); 
$last.parent().parent().effect("highlight", {color: '#FCF8DC'}, 2000);
```

HTML

```
<div class="invoice-line">
    <div class="prod-id-cell"><input type="text" class="prod-id-input"></div>
    <div class="prod-name-cell"><input type="text"class="prod-name-input"/></div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help in accomplishing this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: We're stumbling in the dark without some HTML.

Comment: This is what you need: [addBack](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), take a look at [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) as well.

Comment: find() traverses all descendants, not just children. This should do what you're describing.

Comment: if you selector produces too much entries, try to be more exact, e. g. by using *:first-child or whatever fit your needs.

Comment: What the heck is inner-most parent, are you sure you just don't need to addBack() the latest parent().

Comment: This whole approach seems needlessly complex, but it's hard to say without seeing some code.

Comment: Which element are you acting on, and which is the target?

Comment: Why don't you set up a fiddle, here's one that just needs some adjustment -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Da5tw/), and tell us what exactly the problem is ??

Comment: @isherwood, invoice line from the html corresponds to the rightmost `parent()` in the JQuery. addBack() is not what I need. I need to select the rightmost parent element from the jquery code above in addition to all found descendent elements.

Comment: Everyone seems to think you need `.addBack()`. I think you need `.addBack()`. If you genuinely don't need `.addBack()` then the problem is misdescribed.

Comment: You probably need fix `.find('*')` which is a scatter-gun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$last.parent().parent().find('*').addBack().effect(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addBack()`:

```
$last.parent().parent().find('*').addBack().effect("highlight", {color: '#FCF8DC'}, 2000);
```